# Digest Authorizarion with Fetch and MongoDb Atlas

Tags: javascript, authorization, fetch, mongodb-atlas, digest-authentication

I'm trying to digest authorize the MongoDB Atlas using the Fetch API.

For now I'm doing in this way...

First request:

```
 const res = fetch(
  "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0?pretty=true",
  {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json"
    },
  }
);
```

Then I receive the response with **nonce**, **realm**, **qop** = "auth" and **algorithm** = "MD5":

```
Response {
  url: "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0?pretty=true",
  status: 401,
  statusText: "Unauthorized",
  type_: "default",
  trailer: Promise { <pending> },
  headers: Headers { www-authenticate: Digest realm="XXXXXX", domain="", nonce="4FAFnXrXXXXXXXXXXXXX6dxlXUf", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth", stale=false, content-type: application/json, content-length: 106 },
  body: Body { contentType: "application/json", locked: false, body: [Circular] },
  type: "default",
  redirected: false
}
```

Now, I do a second request with a MD5 Hash to really authorize it.

How the quality of protection (qop) is equal "auth", I use the bellow logic by **rfc2617**

In the MongoAtlas Docs says that publicKey is equal username and the privatekey is equal password, then:

```js
const HA1 = md5(`${publicKey}:${realm}:${privateKey}`)
const HA2 = md5(`${method}:${digestURI}`)
const response = md5(`${HA1}:${nonce}:${HA2}`)
```

I'm not sure what should I put in the digestURI, I think this is it:

```
const digestURI = "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0?pretty=true"
```

The Second Fetch Request I made this way:

```
const digest_header = `username="${publicKey}", realm="${realm}", nonce="${nonce}", uri="${digestURI}", algorithm="MD5", response="${response}", qop="auth"`;


const res2 = fetch(
  "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0?pretty=true",
  {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Digest ${digest_header}`,
    },
  }
);
```

And still receiving an 401 Unauthorized

**UPDATES**
I fixed the header and it's work! I'm not receiving a 401 anymore. But now I'm receiving an 500 server internal error

```js
Response {
  url: "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0?pretty=true",
  status: 500,
  statusText: "Internal Server Error",
  type_: "default",
  trailer: Promise { <pending> },
  headers: Headers { content-type: application/json, content-length: 48 },
  body: Body { contentType: "application/json", locked: false, body: [Circular] },
  type: "default",
  redirected: false
}
```

How make it with Fetch? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Having spent too long down the rabbit hole of getting this to work with Fetch on its own I went with the solution presented here:

https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/nodejs-python-ruby-atlas-api/

It uses this plugin for Fetch:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/digest-fetch

Worked out of the box.